# Font used in Spivak's textbook, "Calculus"

Tags: fonts

Does anyone knows what's the font used in Michael Spivak's "Calculus" and "Calculus on Manifolds" ? I think they're not the same font. The point is that they're both very good fonts, and I didn't find any information anywhere.

Can someone point out what fonts were used?

**Edit:** Bellow there's a screenshot of Calculus:

[image]

And bellow there's a screenshot of Calculus on Manifolds:

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: If you have it in pdf format, you can use the linux utility pdffonts to find out what fonts are in it.

Comment: Actually this is answered in an appendix to DG1. He made the fonts himself.

Answer (score 19):

Spivak's Calculus is typeset in Baskerville font, as the author states [here](http://tug.org/pracjourn/2006-1/spivak/spivak.pdf), in the beginning paragraph remembering how the original MathTıme fonts were born:

> If,
>   20-some years ago, when I was contemplating the next edition of my Calculus book, some one had offered me a
>   reasonable set of math fonts (ones that could be used with Times, or with the Baskerville font in which Calculus
>   is typeset) for the modest price of $1,000, say, then I would have jumped at the chance to obtain it.

Comment: Not really, if the linked article is to be believed the math font is MathTimes (designed by Spivak himself), sold at [PCTeX.com](PCTeX.com).

Comment: But at the same time the text font is Baskerville, as stated at the forth line in the linked text: "the Baskerville font in which Calculus
is typeset"

Comment: You are right, somehow I misread OP as asking specifically for the math font only.

Comment: What about Calculus on Manifolds?

Comment: @fctaylor25, it was pointed out in a comment by egreg to a now deleted answer that the font is (some variant of) Monotype Modern.