# Use text font for alphanumeric characters in math

Tags: math-mode, fonts, math-fonts

My document currently uses *TeX Gyre Termes* as the main text font and *Computer Modern* for math. I would like to continue using *Computer Modern* for math mode symbols, operators, and greek, but replace the normal roman and italic alphanumeric characters (a-z A-Z 0-9) with the corresponding ones from the text font.

In short, I would like to go from the above equation to the below equation.

[image: math with text font]

The code for the mockup perhaps helps to illustrate the point further:

```
I would like to go from this,
\begin{equation}
    2 \, \alpha \, v \begin{pmatrix}
        \cos(t) \\
        \sin(t)
    \end{pmatrix} \;,
\end{equation}
to this,
\begin{equation}
    \mbox{2} \, \alpha \, \mbox{\textit v} \begin{pmatrix}
        \mbox{cos}(\mbox{\textit t}) \\
        \mbox{sin}(\mbox{\textit t})
    \end{pmatrix}\;.
\end{equation}
As you can see, the number 2, the italic ``\textit{v}'' and ``\textit{t}'', and
the upright ``cos'', ``sin'' are taken from the main text font.
```

Unfortunately, I do not know the correct terminology to refer to these different types of fonts, which makes searching for a solution that much harder.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! In the opinion of many (including me), mixing Times and Computer Modern is hideous!

Comment: I do not disagree, @Bernard.

Comment: Why don't you use `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}`? It's mainly based on TeX Gyre Termes, and the fonts will be consistent.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to match the style of a prior work, which uses this rather odd combination of symbols. And some symbols in Times, especially the bold greek, stick out as completely different.

Comment: If only bold Greek is concerned, you can change it in your preamble while keeping the rest of the fonts  configuration.

Comment: The operators (sums, integrals) are conspicuously Computer Modern as well, unfortunately. As it is, the difference between what I get and what I try to mimic is much less noticeable then what it would be for `newtxmath` with CM greek.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By chance, I found the answer in [a comment to an unrelated question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100329/is-a-real-baskerville-font-available-for-latex#comment217389_100385).

There is a [mathastext](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathastext) package that

> uses a text font (usu­ally the doc­u­ment’s text font) for the let­ters of the Latin al­pha­bet needed when type­set­ting math­e­mat­ics. (Op­tion­ally, other char­ac­ters in the font may also be used).

There are a number of examples available in the [showcase](http://jf.burnol.free.fr/showcase.html).