# What's the font name of librebaskerville?

Tags: fonts, xetex

I can load the package 'librebaskerville' but I can't seem to refer to it in commands that take the name of a font.

Here's a short .tex file to demonstrate:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{librebaskerville}

% All of these fail
%\newfontfamily{\smallcaps}[RawFeature={+c2sc,+scmp}]{librebaskerville}
\newfontfamily{\smallcaps}[RawFeature={+c2sc,+scmp}]{Libre Baskerville}
%\newfontfamily{\smallcaps}[RawFeature={+c2sc,+scmp}]{LibreBaskerville}

\begin{document}
Some text.
\end{document}
```

Running with `latexmk -xelatex` (on both Ubuntu 18.04 and OSX 12.4), this generates an error message like this:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty))kpathsea:make_tex: Invalid filename `Libre Baskerville', contains ' '


! Package fontspec Error: The font "Libre Baskerville" cannot be found.
```

What name is needed to refer to the librebaskerville font in commands like `\newfontfamily`, `\setmathsfont`, and `\setmathrm`? Or how could I find out? (I already did a bunch of googling.)

---

Update: The above .tex file works on Overleaf.

Comment: Note that it is a good idea to mention which engine you are using. As e.e. lualatex is much more forgiven than xelatex.

Comment: Note you can also use the file name as well as the internal font name (this is required for xetex texlive fonts unless you have configured fontconfig to index texlive)

Comment: Your document works without error for me in texlive 2022 xelatex and lualatex (with fontconfig set up for xetex)    https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/619577/1090

Comment: @daleif Thanks! I just edited the question to say that I ran `latexmk -xelatex`. Is there anything else I need to do to indicate the engine?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks! I will try upgrading to TeX Live 2022. And thanks for that link to your answer to a similar question: that might be the crucial piece of the puzzle.

Comment: @BenKovitz 2022, 2021, 2020 are all the same as far as this is concerned.

Comment: you can use `LibreBaskerville-Regular.ttf` if you want to load by file name

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Hmm, `\newfontfamily{\smallcaps}[RawFeature={+c2sc,+scmp}]{LibreBaskerville-Regular.ttf}` got the same error as above. I'll try editing `/etc/fonts/local.conf` next.

Comment: check your do works with luatex, also I have no idea where fontconfig looks for fonts on a mac (or ven if xetex uses fontconfig on a mac, you'll need to check) basically do whatever you would do to make a font known to safari

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well, it turns out that `LibreBaskerville-Regular.otf` worked! This even worked as the math font with `mathspec`. Would you like to post that as an answer? I can edit it to include the LaTeX code to get the math font. Small caps isn't working, but I can live with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the inimitable @egreg gave an answer that got to the root of your problem, nobody’s yet given a completely literal one, and someone who finds this page in a search might be looking for one.

A good way to find a font by name from the command line is

```
luaotfload-tool --find "Libre Baskerville" --fuzzy
```

If the name is correct, this will display the full path of the file.

If that doesn’t get you the exact match—if you had only remembered that it was some version of Baskerville—`--fuzzy` would have told you that the closest match was `BaskervilleF`.  If it finds the wrong font, you can tell it to show the top few matches.  So,

```
luaotfload-tool --find "Baskerville" --fuzzy --limit=4
```

on my box gives me

```
luaotfload | db : Reload initiated (formats: otf,ttf,ttc); reason: Font "Baskerville" not found.
luaotfload | resolve : sequence of 3 lookups yielded nothing appropriate.
luaotfload | resolve : Cannot find "Baskerville" in index.
luaotfload | resolve : Looking for close matches, this may take a while ...
luaotfload | query : Distance from "baskerville": 1
    BaskervilleF
luaotfload | query : Distance from "baskerville": 3
    ADFBaskerville
    GFSBaskerville-Regular
luaotfload | query : Distance from "baskerville": 5
    BaskervilleF Bold
    Libre Baskerville
luaotfload | query : Distance from "baskerville": 6
    QTBasker-Bold
```

It’s also possible to give more complex queries to either `luaotfload-tool`, `fc-match` or `fc-search`, but the above is usually what you want.

At this point, you want to check for a file named `LibreBaskerville.fontspec`, with a filename search or `kpsewhich LibreBaskerville.fontspec`.  If that existed, all configuration would be done for you and `\setmainfont{LibreBaskerville}` would load it.  In this case, however, it does not.

Once you have the path, searching the directory will give you the filenames of the fonts in the family.  In this case: `LibreBaskerville-Bold.ttf`, `LibreBaskerville-Italic.ttf`, `LibreBaskerville-Regular.ttf` and `LibreBskvl-BoldItalic.ttf`.  The recommended way to load this family is by filename, like in egreg’s answer, although I usually do it slightly differently in case I need to re-use the same font family:

```
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\defaultfontfeatures[LibreBaskerville]{
  Extension=.ttf,
  UprightFont    = *-Regular,
  ItalicFont     = *-Italic,
  BoldFont       = *-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont = LibreBskvl-BoldItalic,
  SmallCapsFont  = BaskervilleF-Regular.otf,
  SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps},
  Ligatures={Common,Discretionary,TeX}
}

% I don’t want to repeat all of the above multiple times when I select the
% same font more than once, and probably introduce inconsistencies.
\setmainfont{LibreBaskerville}
\newfontfamily\baskerville{LibreBaskerville}
```

However, there is also another way.  If you tell `luaotfload-tool` to display font information and not just the filename, it will give you all the font’s internal names.  So,

```
luaotfload-tool --find "Libre Baskerville" -i
```

will give you a big dump that includes

```
compatiblename: Libre Baskerville
        family: Libre Baskerville
      fontname: LibreBaskerville-Regular
```

and a number of others.  Normally, `fontspec` should be able to find the font by one of these names, but it doesn’t always work.

Comment: Ah, I'm glad to see a direct answer to the question. I did not know about `Scale=MatchLowercase`. I'll be putting that to use. I'm getting the error message "Misplaced equals sign in key-value input on line 125" on `\newfontfamily\baskerville{LibreBaskerville}`. Any suggestions?

Comment: I just fixed that error: a missing comma (I added it to your answer). It looks like `Scale=MatchLowercase` reduced the font size throughout the whole document, so I took that out. But I will use it later to scale Friz Quadrata, which is interspersed with the body text. Thanks! I'll accept this answer barring any surprises showing up in the next day or so.

Answer (score 1):

If I look for the features of the LibreBaskerville font distributed with TeX Live in

```
.../texmf-dist/fonts/truetype/impallari/librebaskerville/
```

by doing

```bash
otfinfo -f $(kpsewhich LibreBaskerville-Regular.ttf)
```

I get

```
dlig    Discretionary Ligatures
frac    Fractions
kern    Kerning
liga    Standard Ligatures
ordn    Ordinals
sinf    Scientific Inferiors
sups    Superscript
```

which reveals that small caps are not supported.

To the contrary, BaskervilleF does support them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{LibreBaskerville}[
  Extension=.ttf,
  UprightFont    = *-Regular,
  ItalicFont     = *-Italic,
  BoldFont       = *-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont = LibreBskvl-BoldItalic,
  SmallCapsFont  = BaskervilleF-Regular.otf,
  SmallCapsFeatures={Letters=SmallCaps,Scale=1.10791},
]

\begin{document}

Baskerville \textsc{Baskerville}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, it seems that BaskervilleF just scales down capitals. `:-(`

Comment: Wow. It took me a day to get around to looking at your answer closely because I actually wasn't all that concerned with small capitals, just how to supply the name of the font to commands that need it. But now I see! I had no idea that you could specify so much in `\setmainfont`. I made two changes to get it to work on my computer: `Extension=.otf` and `BoldItalicFont = *-BoldItalic`, and now, not only do I have the spacious Libre Baskerville to counter my university's dissertation format's requirement of wide lines and small font sizes, I even have small caps!

Comment: Great answer, as usual! Also, `otfinfo -i` will display the family names that the question was literally asking for, although if you have the filenames of the font family, it’s recommended to just use those.

Answer (score 1):

If you run the test document with lualatex it will confirm you have the font, and at the end of the log will show its full path. You can use the filename with `fontspec` which is easier to make work with xetex than the internal font name. In this case that is `LibreBaskerville-Regular.otf`